# Dell Quickset missing menu on system tray

Tags: windows-7, dell-vostro, osd

I've bought a **Dell Vostro 15 3568** notebook. I am using it with Windows 7 64bit.

Now the problem. I've installed the latest available Quickset Application (25 Apr 2017) from the Dell support site. The on-screen indicators work fine, and I have an icon on the system tray, but it does not react to left or right clicks. I can't open a menu or a window.

Is it supposed to work like that? I've found reviews and tutorials on the internet about much older versions of the application, which showed the ability to fine tune the application using a contextual menu. Is it possible that the devs at Dell dumbed it down? If so, why do I have the tray icon at all? If not, how can I repair it?

Comment: Have you restarted the PC to see if it fixes itself?

Comment: Yes, I have. The program loads on start up, as I can see the indicators on the screen, and the button appears on the system tray.